# Not able to stop mysql --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking?

Tags: networking, server, permissions, xubuntu, mysql

I used "--skip-grant-tables --skip-networking" command for reset root password. But after that my database running on the same mode. I completely uninstall mysql from my Ubuntu 18.0 by below commands-

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

After reinstalling mysql It's automatically running with **--skip-grant-tables --skip-networking**

user:~$ ps aux | grep mysqld

```
mysql     8463  8.3  2.2 1290748 177096 ?      Sl   13:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
sunil     8518  0.0  0.0  21532  1088 pts/0    S+   13:17   0:00 grep --color=auto mysqld
```

please help me to stop   **--skip-grant-tables --skip-networking**